# psql prompt changes to "-#" and the statement isn't committed

Tags: postgresql, psql, prompt

I'm new to Postgres and I set up a database and table.  On the Ubuntu 18.04 command line (on a cloud server) I issued the following command using `psql`:

```
INSERT INTO psq01(date, email, firstname, lastname, password, comments)
   VALUES ("052419", "mjs@outlook.com", "John", "Smith", "blank", "No comment")
```

After I issue that command, the `psql` command prompt switches from `=#` to `-#`, which means the transaction is not finished, so I issued `COMMIT`, but the prompt still shows as `-#`.

My question is:  what do I do after an `insert into` command?  Why am I getting the `-#` prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dbname-#` prompt means that `psql` is waiting for a continuation line because you haven't terminated the statement with a semiculon (`;`) yet.

Either type a single semicolon and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the command or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt it and start over.

Are you sure that you want to use a superuser for inserting into a table?

Comment: good point about the superuser - I think I should precede the command with sudo because I'm not logged as root.  But this is just a test.  Ordinarily I will insert from a web page.

Comment: I mean that the `#` at the end of the prompt tells that you are a *database* superuser. Normal users have a prompt that ends in `>`.

Comment: I just did what you said, and it does return me to the =# prompt but it reports 'syntax error at or near "sudo"'.  I can't tell what the error is.  When I remove sudo, it reports:  " column "052419" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ail,firstname,lastname,password,comments) VALUES ("052419", ..." but that's not a column, it's a value.

Comment: String literals are surrouded by single quotes in SQL, but that is a different issue.

Comment: To follow this up, I altered my string to :  INSERT INTO psq01(date,email,firstname,lastname,password,comments) VALUES ('052419','mjs@outlook.com','John','Smith','blank','No comment') and that works but it reports "date/time field value out of range: INT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting".  So now I have the correct command; I'll work out the date field issue.  Thanks very much for your help.